# Mutate in R: how to count the number of changes made

Tags: r, count, dplyr

I am doing a mutate of a column like:

```
new_data <- my_data %>% mutate(col1 = ifelse(col2==0 & col3!=0, 0, col1))
```

I would like to know how many rows were affected. I guess I can count how many `clo2 == 0 & col3 != 0`, but is there a function or a quick way to get that result?

A following question would be to also flag the variables which were affected in addition to know the number of them.

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag. In particular complete test cases including all inputs and library statements should be included in questions.

Comment: The sum function would come in handy here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most elegant (or memory-friendly!) solution, but you could create a copy of the column in a mutate call, make your changes, and then compare the two columns for equality.

```
library(dplyr)
    my_iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(Species = as.character(Species), # using characters makes this simpler
         Species_copy = Species, # our copy of Species
         Species = if_else(Species == "virginica", "pretty_flower", Species)) # making changes to data frame

# Finding the number of changes
sum(my_iris$Species != my_iris$Species_copy)
#> 50
```

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of rows where the conditions meet:

```
nrow(my_data %>% filter(col2==0 & col3!=0))
```

It will give you the number of rows that will be changed

And to know the number of **rows** affected, you can create a new column which indicates if the rows is changed or not:

```
my_data %>%
  mutate(indic = ifelse(col2==0 & col3!=0, 1, 0))
```

With `1` if changed, `0` if not